# Anonymous inner class in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, wicket, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I am looking into the groovy-wicket integration and lack of anonymous inner classes seems to be a problem when writing the event handlers.
Is there a groovier way of writing this code

```
import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage


/**
 * Homepage
 */
class HomePage extends WebPage {


    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {

        // Add the simplest type of label
        add(new Label("message", "Wicket running!"));   
        def link1 = new ClickHandler("link1") //in java, defined inline
        add(link1);
    }   
}

class ClickHandler extends Link{

    ClickHandler(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    void onClick(){println "Hi"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but isn't this what the [WickeBuilder](http://wicketstuff.org/confluence/display/STUFFWIKI/WicketBuilder) tries to solve:

> The Wicket Builder utility implements
>   a Groovy Builder for constructing
>   Wicket Component trees.
>
> While using the builder makes building
>   Component trees easier and more clear
>   to the reader, the original driver was
>   the fact that Groovy does not allow
>   anonymous inner classes.  Wicket
>   relies on overriding methods to
>   provide custom functionality for many
>   Component types.  Groovy can be used
>   to code Wicket page classes, but each
>   class that is overridden needs a named
>   class definition.  Possible, but
>   clunky.
>
> The WicketBuilder simulates these
>   overrides with named Closures. 
>   Closures are, essentially, portable
>   code blocks.  Under the hood, the
>   builder creates dynamic class
>   overrides and runs the closures when
>   the named method is called.
>
> [...]

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Alas, it seems that the projects hasn't seen a lot of activity as of late. Anyway, this problem surely affects other frameworks as well. There is a talk about implementing inner classes in future version of groovy.

Comment: Indeed, Groovy anonymous inner classes are on the Roadmap for 1.8 http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Groovy+Roadmap

Comment: Anonymous inner classes are due in Groovy 1.7

Comment: Indeed, 1.7 as written in the roadmap (1.8 is a typo).

Answer (score 1):

Ermh.. This doesn't look like a "good" alternative, but it seems to be the "official" Groovy alternative:

[Groovy Alternatives to Inner Classes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Alternatives+to+Inner+Classes)

Comment: I am aware of the link, but had no success in following the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Comlete example for groovy 1.7.x and wicket 1.4.x http://wash-inside-out.blogspot.com/2010/08/wicket-and-groovy-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

i actually do not use groovy often, but asked me the same question few month ago. i tried out different approaches

http://rschmid.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/anonymouse-inner-classes-in-groovy/

Answer (score 0):

Groovy 1.7 and above support anonymous inner classes. See groovy 1.7 [release notes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.7+release+notes).

Comment: I'm using grails and groovy 1.6.4 is still bundled with 1.2 M3 version of grials. Is there a way to make grails use new version of groovy?